# Factory not getting constructed service manager class

Tags: zend-framework2

Here is my service configuration:

```
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Squiddle\Designpackage' => function($sm){                  
                    $designPkg = new Designpackage($sm);
                    return $designPkg;
                }
            )   
        );
    }
```

**It's being used within a function that gets triggered on the dispatch event.**

Here is it's usage:

```
$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Squiddle\Designpackage');
```

My error is that the designpackage is being constructed with null instead of a service manager.

Not sure whats wrong here;

Comment: most likely it does not use your configured factory its hard to say where you missconfigured it. maybe cache enabled or module is not loaded or not added into application.config.php etc..

Comment: I would say your factory method is never called. Can you try debugging (or dirty test put a `var_dump` or `die` call in your factory method).

Answer (score -1):

It could be a problem in the Designpackage constructor

Comment: This is more of a commment than an answer.